# Access parent element(body) in directive link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Given a HTML structure similar to this:

```
<body>
    <div id="one" my-directive></div>
    <div>
        <div id="two" my-directive></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I try to access the parent element of `two` It works and the log returns the parent div, but when the parent is the body, as in `one` case, it doesn't work and returns an empty set.

```
app.directive 'myDirective', ->
    (scope,iElement,iAttrs) ->
        console.log iElement.parent()
```

**EDIT:** My guess for this problem is that my app's body is rendered on client side and appended to the body element on module's run method. The html is inserted with  `$('body').html($compile(body.render())($rootScope));` and I suppose the directive is called within the $compile function before the contents are inserted in the body. Can I work around this problem?

Comment: Seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/mTNvq/

Comment: That's weird, now I have some clues of what might be the problem.

Comment: Try using [$evalAsync](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) (executes after Angular digest cycle, hence after Angular DOM manipulations, but before browser render) or [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) (executes after browser render) in your link function.

Comment: Where is the ng-app ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you understood your problem correctly: `$compile` will trigger the template compilation and linking phases on your element, so it has no parent while doing so.

The easy way to fix that is to first append your HTML to the body, and *then* compile it.

```
var html = body.render();
$('body').html(html);
$compile(angular.element(body))($rootScope);
```

Or if you don't want to compile the whole body but just the new element:

```
var elem = $( body.render() ).appendTo($('body'));
$compile(elem)($rootScope);
```